# finding pattern in a file

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a txt file of 500 rows and one column.

The column in each row appears some what like this (as an example I am pasting two rows):

```
chr22:49367820-49368570_NR_021492_LOC100144603,chr22:49368010-49368760_NM_005198_CHKB,chr22:49368010-49368760_NM_152247_CPT1B,chr22:49368010-49368760_NM_152253_CHKB    

chr22:49367820-49368570_NR_021492_LOC100144603,chr22:49368010-49368760_NM_005198_CHKB
```

Want I want to extract from each row is the values starting from NM_ or NR_
like

- row 1 has `NR_021492 NM_005198 NM_152247 NM_152253`
- row 2 has `NR_021492 NM_005198`
- ...

in tab delimited file

any suggestions for a bash command line?

Comment: delimited with tab but one column ?

Comment: Hi John! It can be in one column but separated by a dash (-). ideally would like to have them in different columns.

Comment: Is it correct that the `chr22` part is always static?

Comment: @Sorpigal: the static part is chr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 sed -r -e 's/chr[0-9]+:[^_]*_(N[RM])_([0-9]+)_[^,_]+([, ]|$)/\1_\2'$'\t''/g;s/'$'\t''$//g'
```

Presuming GNU sed.

So

```
sed -r -e 's/chr[0-9]+:[^_]*_(N[RM])_([0-9]+)_[^,_]+([, ]|$)/\1_\2'$'\t''/g;s/'$'\t''$//g' your_file > tab_delimited_file
```

EDIT: Updated to not leave a trailing tab character on each row.

EDIT 2: Updated again to work for any chr-then-number sequence.

Comment: hey your answer nearly solved the problem.But not completely, here is a sample data set for you ROW1 chr1:6684303-6685053_NM_018198_DNAJC11

Comment: @Angelo: I did ask whether `chr22` was static. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Sorpigal, `sed -r 's/[^_]*_(N[RM]_[0-9]+)_[^,_]+([, ]|$)/\1\t/g'  infile`

Comment: @John: \t is not portable and I prefer the explicit reference to `chr`, but otherwise your version is indeed superior. One capture is better than two.

Comment: @Sorpigal: i don't know much about portablity. thanks for the info. +1.

Comment: @Sorpigal: now one last edit requested in your wonderful script. Consider if I have to apply this application on a file which has 4 columns and 4 column is the one where these NM or NR identifiers are present (which I am able to extract from your script). Now I want to extract the values in first three column as well if the 4 column has NM or/and NR identifier present in it.

Comment: @Angelo: That's a completely separate problem and I recommend a separate question for it. The solution would likely not involve sed at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep "NM" yourfiname | cut -d_ -f3 | sed 's/[/\d]*/NM_/'
grep "NR" yourfiname | cut -d_ -f3 | sed 's/[/\d]*/NR_/'
```

Comment: This fails by assuming only one NR or MR on block in each row. The input data may only have one "column" but the output should have multiple.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat file|sed s/$.*!(NR)//;
```

Use a regular expression to remove everything before the NR

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F '[,:_-]' '{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) 
        if ($i == "NR" || $i == "NM") 
            printf("%s_%s ", $i, $(i+1))
    print ""
}'
```

This will also work, but will print each match on its own line: `egrep -o 'N[RM]_[0-9]+`